# Abbreviation for template arguments (Vector3 instead of Vector<3>)

Tags: c++, templates

Consider a `template`

```
template<int size>
class Vector{
public:
  double data[size];
}
```

is there a possiblity for defining abbreviation that one can write something like

```
Vector3 a;
```

instead of

```
Vector<3> a;
```

for general values of `size`?

Comment: No. The only types you can use in templates are `class` and `typename` (which are now equivalent).

Comment: @ciuak No, int is a valid type in templates.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a specialization particularly often, just use a typedef:

```
using Vector3 = Vector<3>;
```

Comment: is there also a possibilty for general size?

Comment: @Matthias No. `Vector3` is an identifier and has to be declared first.

Comment: Thought there is some method using `typedef Vector<size> Vector##size;` Or something like that..

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward example is `typedef Vector<3> Vector3;`